# Troubleshooting 'File specified in the modules section of this template already exists.' error in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have site definition in Visual Studio 2010 for SharePoint 2010 site, which has multiple features. When the site is deployed through powershell, all features are activated properly but an interesting event occurs -- receivers in feature apparently fail to fire.

And when I manually deactivate one particular feature and try to activate it again, I receive the following error:

> File specified in the modules section of this template already exists.

I have tried http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010 to find out more about error but can't really find out which file is throwing up the error.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to set to True the IgnoreIfAlreadyExists attribute in the elements.xml of your feature.

```
<File Path="Style Library\whatever.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary"  IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" />
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: How can i possibly find out which file is giving the issues and need to make changes to same? any way for it?

Comment: 1- Try to reproduce the error again, then copy the correlation id that is showed in the error.

2- Then go to the SharePoint file system (in general is located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS)

3- Open the latest modified log with any notepad and search by the correlation id copied before.

4- You'll see a couple of lines with the same correlation id and you can see the entire error message as well. There should be the name of the file is causing trouble.